# Using Gamma integration vs Integration By Parts to solve for variance of a double exponential variable

Tags: calculus, statistics, gamma-function, variance, integration-by-parts

For the textbook explanation of this problem (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYFdT.jpg), in step 2, they use the gamma function in order to integrate the integral. But this gives them a result of 1/lambda?

In this, I substituted lambda for 5 (random number i picked) to check the integration, which I did by parts twice instead of the gamma integration.

https://www.symbolab.com/solver/definite-integral-calculator/5%5Ccdot%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dx%5E%7B2%7De%5E%7B-5x%7D%20dx

And the answer would end up being 2/lambda^2 ? This difference is huge and I'm really confused and convinced their integration isn't correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the problem more general, the link you give seems to address the problem of $$I_n=\int x^n\, e^{-\lambda x}\, dx$$ (in which $\lambda >0$). You can compute the antiderivative by a series of integration by parts of use the definition of the gamma function to get $$I_n=-x^{n+1} (\lambda  x)^{-(n+1)}\,\Gamma (n+1,x \lambda )$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.

Concerning $$J_n=\int_0^\infty x^n\, e^{-\lambda x}\, dx=\lambda ^{-(n+1)} \,\Gamma (n+1)$$ provided that $\Re(\lambda )>0\land \Re(n)>-1$. If $n$ is an integer, it reduces to $$J_n=\lambda ^{-(n+1)} n!$$

So, in step $2$, if I am not wrong, it should be $$E(x^2)=\lambda \int_0^\infty x^2\, e^{-\lambda x}\, dx=\frac 2 {\lambda^2}$$